# Google Tag Manager custom event (product page views) not firing tags

Tags: google-tag-manager

I tried to set up a tag that should be firing when a customer goes on the product page.

I found out in the dataLayer that there is this object:  pageType: 'product'

After that I used this object in my trigger as so:

[image: Picture of trigger]

In the tag itself, I made sure that enhanced ecommerce was enabled, and also checked the checkbox that dataLayer is being used, however it is still not firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need is to create a custom variable to capture the information stored in the dataLayer.

In the main menu, click variables:
[image: GTM variables menu]

Click on the button "New" in the User Defined Variables section.
Name the variable DLV - pageType, select Variable Type Data Layer Variable name it pageType and hit Save when you are done:
[image: User Defined dataLayer variable]

Next, click on Triggers in the main menu to add a new trigger. Name the trigger, select Page View as trigger type, Only Some Page Views and make sure it only fires when DLV - productType equals product:
[image]

Now the only thing that is left is to configure the tag to the trigger.